# How would I filter this dataset?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have a dataset that looks like the image. I'm trying to filter by table and get all the columns next to it and compare them against other datasets

[image]

This dataset has tables named table 1 and table 2 and when they're selected they look like the picture below. It shows the columns and I need to compare those columns against the rows from the matching table in the first dataset [image]

I've looked at dataview but that would be a lot of work and I'm very inexperienced. I'm trying to find a way to implement a foreach loop that'll get the name of the table in the first dataset and then compare the rows in it against the columns inside the datatable in the second dataset that matched the table name from the first dataset.

Comment: Please do not post images of datasets, post it in text and format it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about these `DataSets` (like do they have primary keys, the data types of the columns, the number of rows in each table, etc), I can only provide limited help.  The following example tries to be as general as possible and avoid some basic problems:

```
DataSet ds1 = <<fetch dataset1>>;
DataSet ds2 = <<fetch dataset2>>;
foreach (DataTable tbl1 in ds1.Tables)
{
    if (ds2.Tables.Contains(tbl1.TableName))
    {
        DataTable tbl2 = ds2.Tables[tbl1.TableName];
        List<string> commonColumnNames = new List<string>(tbl1.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => c.ColumnName).Intersect(tbl2.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => c.ColumnName)));
        int maxRows = Math.Min(tbl1.Rows.Count, tbl2.Rows.Count);
        for (int r = 0; r <= maxRows; r++)
        {
            foreach (string colName in commonColumnNames)
            {
               if (tbl1.Rows[r][colName] != tbl2.Rows[r][colName])
               {
                    // Different value
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update 1:** I've added comments to the following example to explain step-by-step what this code is doing. As I try to say before, since I didn't know much about your data, I had to put in extra code. This extra code is for things like: 'Does the table `ABC` exist in both DataSets?', 'Do the two tables have the same columns in them?', 'Do the tables have the same number of rows in them?'. Your original question did not have this information, so I made this code a little more robust to handle those unknowns.

```
DataSet ds1 = <<fetch dataset1>>;
DataSet ds2 = <<fetch dataset2>>;

// Loop through all of the tables in the 1st DataSet
foreach (DataTable tbl1 in ds1.Tables)
{
    // If the 2nd DataSet has a table with same name as the one from the 1st DataSet
    if (ds2.Tables.Contains(tbl1.TableName))
    {
        DataTable tbl2 = ds2.Tables[tbl1.TableName];
        // Create a list of column names that the two tables have in common.
        // We will only compare the values in these two tables, in this set of matching column names.

        List<string> commonColumnNames = new List<string>(tbl1.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => c.ColumnName).Intersect(tbl2.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => c.ColumnName)));
        // Before we start comparing the rows in the two tables, find out which one has the fewer number of rows in it.
        int maxRows = Math.Min(tbl1.Rows.Count, tbl2.Rows.Count);
        // If the tables have a different number of rows, then we will only compare the set of rows numbered 0-to-MinRowCount
        for (int r = 0; r <= maxRows; r++)
        {
            // For each row, compare the values of common columns
            foreach (string colName in commonColumnNames)
            {
               if (tbl1.Rows[r][colName] != tbl2.Rows[r][colName])
               {
                    // Different value
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what the code is basically doing? I'm very new at this.

Comment: @Luis - I've updated my answer with a new "Update 1" that has my sample code with a bunch of comments to explain what each line is attempting.